# Wordpress Simple AJAX Get Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've got a JavaScript file that's using AJAX to get a PHP file that has WordPress functions and simple HTML in. My JavaScript file is working fine with the jQuery functionality inside to grab my file, but as the file has WordPress functionality inside, it's giving WordPress errors because the WordPress functionality obviously isn't included--this is being used on the front-end.

**AJAX Call**

```
$.ajax({
    url: wnm_custom.template_url + "/admin/includes/header1.php",
        success: function(html) {
        $("body").append(html);
        }
    });
```

Do I have to load the AJAX through WordPress and if so surely it would be simple as the functionality is working just the WordPress functionality is not?

All the WordPress functions within my header1.php file are just undefined.

**Edit**

```
$.ajax({
    url: wnm_custom.template_url.ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {action: "get_top_main"},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });

function get_top_main() {
    include(get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/includes/header1.php'); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_top_main', 'get_top_main_up');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_top_main', 'get_top_main_up');
```

This is what I've come up now but for some reason the response is the complete page syntax... (maybe because the URL is pointed to .ajaxurl), it doesn't seem to be calling the function.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? (i mean, the requirement). you just wanted to echo whatever inside header1.php or you want to get the header part of a wordpress site?

Comment: I'm trying to get everything out of header1.php which is basically just a header - basically echo everything inside header1.php but it has WordPress functions in there that error upon pulling them through.

Comment: you have to write a wordpress plugin which returns only the header part

Comment: I think you mis-understood, everything is being included fine, except the WP functions don't work because there's no link to wp-load.php - instead of just including the file (which is wrong apparently), surely there's a simple way--surely I don't have to write a plugin?

Comment: Why aren't you using `admin-ajax.php` as recommended? http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your Ajax calls should point to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` as described in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

In your case, you're querying the PHP file `header1.php` directly, so WordPress isn't loaded at that time and you won't be able to use any WordPress functions in it.

Comment: Just done a quick update and it seems to be giving me a full page response of my current page (which is not what I'm expecting).

Comment: Include your `header1.php` file in your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: It's not even entering the action though.

Comment: What you need to confirm: Did you define `wnm_custom.template_url.ajaxurl`? Is the request you're sending good? Is there a website live that I can have a look?

Comment: Your include part looks weird. It shouldn't be in a function and you should include it as `__DIR__ . '/admin/includes/header1.php'`

Comment: I've got it so it enters the function now and it's including, but I'm getting include errors (with both the include of mine and yours): Warning: include(): Failed opening and it's giving me back a '0' response.

Comment: Fixed that problem, seemed to be an 'include' problem, seems to work with require instead. Seems to have fixed everything, thanks :)